# real-time sync between local Postgres instance and Azure Cloud Postgres instance

Tags: postgresql, synchronization, replication, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I need to set up real time sync process between a on premise postgresql instance with cloud postgresql instance. Please let me know what are all the options available through which i can achieve it.

Do i have to use any specific tool or it can be managed through replication .

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

Use PgPool

http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

from their web page:

pgpool-II can manage multiple PostgreSQL servers. Using the replication function enables creating a realtime backup on 2 or more physical disks, so that the service can continue without stopping servers in case of a disk failure.