# How to create a postgresql clustered database?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 hosts and want to create a postgresql database spanning both hosts for redundancy. Im a bit confused by the term clustering as it applies to postgresql, as it seems you can create a postgresql cluster on a single node, which is not what im after. I would like to have the data on both hosts and be able to run a query which span resources of both machines at the same time. In addition, if either host goes down, the other should assume the entire workload until the host is restored at which time it needs to re-sync and begin acting as a single database again.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling or https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Clustering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [real-time sync between local Postgres instance and Azure Cloud Postgres instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44248931/real-time-sync-between-local-postgres-instance-and-azure-cloud-postgres-instance)